# $\text{cond}(A)\gt \text{cond}(A+B)$ for $AA^T=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, condition-number

Let $A$ a matrix such that $AA^T=I$. Is there a matrix $B$ such that

$$\text{cond}(A)\gt \text{cond}(A+B)$$

If so give numerical exmples for this, otherwise prove that there isn't.

The condition number is: $\text{cond}(A)=\Vert A\Vert \Vert A^{-1}\Vert$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the spectral norm, the condition number of $A$ is $1$.  But there is no matrix with condition number less than $1$, because $$1 = \|I\| = \|M M^{-1}\| \le \|M \| \|M^{-1}\|$$ for all invertible matrices $M$.

Comment: Hey robert i think this is true only for norm 2 no?

Comment: The inequality is true for all submultiplicative matrix norms.

Comment: I ment that your answer is true only for the case when we do cond with norm 2 because for other norms we can find examples that work for this